# Correct use of a LATERAL FROM

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, lateral

I am trying to use PostGIS to undertake a number of steps within an SQL statement to basically convert a raster to points, buffer, dissolve and then determine the overall boundary i.e. concave hull based on an attribute.

The following is where I am at but get an error suggesting the use of a LATERAL FROM but I do not know what I need to do.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

> [0A000] ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls Hint: You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item. Position: 123

```
 SELECT name,
    st_union(
            st_buffer(
                    st_transform(
                            (ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast, 1)).geom
                        , 32756),
                    50, 2)
        )
 FROM rasters
 where id < 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the function `ST_PixelAsCentroids()` to a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` and give it a label, e.g.

```
SELECT name, ST_ASTEXT(
  ST_Union(
    ST_Buffer(
      ST_Transform((j).geom,32756),
      50, 2))
    )
FROM rasters 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast, 1) j
WHERE id < 5
GROUP BY name;
```

Although you can achieve the same results without the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`

```
SELECT name, ST_ASTEXT(
  ST_Union(
    ST_Buffer(
      ST_Transform((j).geom,32756),
      50, 2))
    )
FROM rasters, ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast, 1) j
WHERE id < 5
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Thanks Jim very much appreciated 